# django reverse foreign key pefetch related, queryset condition not working

Tags: django, django-prefetch-related, django-prefetch

Consider the following condition:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    books = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So, for this query:

```
Book.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('store_set',
            queryset=Store.objects.filter(default=False)))
            .values("store__name", "name", "store__default")
```

The SQL query is not considering queryset **default=True** condition

```
SELECT "core_store"."name",
       "core_book"."name",
       "core_store"."default"
  FROM "core_book"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "core_store"
    ON ("core_book"."id" = "core_store"."books_id")
```

Result:

```
<QuerySet [{'store__name': 'Subway Store', 'name': 'Hello', 'store__default': False}, 
{'store__name': 'Times Square', 'name': 'Hello', 'store__default': False}, 
{'store__name': 'Subway Store', 'name': 'GoodBye', 'store__default': True}, 
{'store__name': 'Times Square', 'name': 'GoodBye', 'store__default': False}, 
{'store__name': 'Subway Store', 'name': 'Greetings', 'store__default': True}, 
{'store__name': 'Subway Store', 'name': 'HateWords', 'store__default': False}]>
```

I want to have a query set condition while prefetching the query. I am not able to find any way to do it in one query or a minimum number of queries.

I was thinking it should make a where condition with the OUTER JOIN with core_store table. Here

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "core_store"
    ON ("core_book"."id" = "core_store"."books_id")
```

Comment: Do you want only the name field from `Book` instances that are related to a `Store` instance?

Comment: No, everything is required as stated above. ```.values("store__name", "name", "store__default")```

Comment: According to the above code, u are querying only `name` from `Book` and remaining 2 fields are from `Store` model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the values as stated in your question then you can directly use `fk` relationship from the `Store` model to `Book` model as below. No need to do reverse lookup.

```
Store.objects.filter(default=True).values('name', 'default', 'books__name')
```

But if u want to fetch all `Book`s and also their corresponding `Store` then you can use `only` on `prefetch_related`. `.values` does not work with `prefetch_related` as stated in the docs. You can also use a `for` loop after assigning a `to_attr` in your `prefetch_related` query. The for loop does not do a db query. Instead it gets the value from `prefetch`ed results.

```
books_stores = Book.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('store_set',
            queryset=Store.objects.filter(default=False), 
            to_attr='stores'))


for book_store in book_stores:
    stores = book_store.stores
```

Comment: unfortunately , this is not what I am looking for, but thanks. This is achievable.

Comment: `.values` does not work with `prefetch_related`. if you are looking for that.